# How to set a deployed printer as default using group-policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, print-server

Using a [windows-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) I added the print-management role to it.

Using that, I added a new printer

[image]

and attached it to a currently set GPO

[image]

Assuming I done things right, looking at the linked GPO - I see the correct values

[image]

In the past, I used the pushprinterconnection.exe to set a printer as default.

Q: Is that STILL the way to set a deployed printer as default?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it through Deployed Printers. If you use Group Policy Preferences then you can choose which printer is default. Give that a go instead.

Comment: What GP preferences?

Comment: Printer preferences...